# Convert flat to hierarchy list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two tables "CategoryGroup" and "Category" which returns data in one list. Requirement is to  convert flat list to hierarchy list like CategoryGroup contains related categories.

[image: Result from both the tables]

Please suggest how to convert into hieararchy list?

```
 public class ProfileConditionGroup
{
    public Guid ConditionGroupGUID { get; set; }
    public string ConditionGroupName { get; set; }
    public List<ProfileConditionList> profileConditions { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileConditionList
{
    public string ConditionName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Guid> ConditionGUID { get; set; }
    public string[] ThisConditionSelectedByProfileIDs { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Guid> ParentConditionGroupGUID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefaultSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `items.GroupBy(x => x.CategoryGroup)` ?

Comment: Please provide the class defs in C# for the two tables.

Comment: @Enigmativity : Post updated

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a little tricky without having an actual concrete return type, but here's the way I'd tackle it if you're just building a tree of `Guid` values.

Given this query:

```
var query =
    from pcg in pcgs
    from pcl in pcg.profileConditions
    select new
    {
        pcg.ConditionGroupName,
        pcg.ConditionGroupGUID,
        pcl.ConditionName,
        pcl.ConditionGUID,
        pcl.ThisConditionSelectedByProfileIDs,
        pcl.ParentConditionGroupGUID,
        pcl.IsDefaultSelected,
    };
```

...I'd do this:

```
var lookup = query.ToLookup(x => x.ParentConditionGroupGUID);

Func<Guid?, Tree<Guid?>> build = null;
build = g =>
{
    var r = new Tree<Guid?>() { Value = g };
    r.AddRange(lookup[g].Select(x => build(x.ConditionGroupGUID)));
    return r;
};
```

Now you just call `build(null)` and you should get a tree of `Guid?`. If you can create you're own output class you'd change the function to `Func<Guid?, Tree<YourOutputClass>>`.

You need this class for the tree:

```
public class Tree<T> : List<Tree<T>>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```